# centre the contents of a login page

Tags: html, css, django

I'm having trouble centring the contents of my login page [image: it looks like this right now]

Can you help me with the styling? I basically want the long input fields to be in the centre and be short like a typical login page.
I had another question regarding bootstrap, I found a code snipped for some component for which I used version 3.4 but I am not able to use the other features of the higher versions for my other components..is there a way around that?

the code is:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}


    <h2>Login</h2>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Can you try this one? 

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-3 text-center">
                    <h2>Login</h2>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
*emphasized text*
    Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No the input block still looks odd

Answer (score 1):

Check out this may help you [Bootstrap flex method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
    
    {% block body %}
      
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    
        <h2>Login</h2>
    
        {% if message %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    
        Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here.</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey it looks good but it's still to the left and not in the centre.

Comment: Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ this if it helps

Comment: Check it i have altered

Answer (score 0):

Used  this and it worked

```
<style>
    body {
    text-align: center;
   

}
form {
    display: inline-block;
   
}
</style>
```